# How to use tensor-flow to reshape [1,2,3,4,5,6] into [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]?

Tags: tensorflow, reshape

I know bellow statement :

```
tf.reshape([1,2,3,4,5,6]，[2, 3]) will get [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

But how to get `[[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tf.transpose( tf.reshape( [1,2,3,4,5,6]，[3,2]))
```

Should work, at least it works in numpy.